# Options for cancelling a task and waiting for its termination

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I need to cancel a pending task and await for its termination before the code flow can continue. Usually, I do this:

```
if (this.task != null)
{
    this.taskCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    try
    {
        await this.task;
        // I don't need to know the result, just log it
        Debug.Print(this.task.Status.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // I don't need to know the result, just log it
        Debug.Print(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I just realized I can do the same without `try/catch`:

```
if (this.task != null)
{
    this.taskCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    await this.task.ContinueWith(
        // I don't need to know the result, just log it
        (t) => Debug.Print(((object)t.Exception ?? (object)t.Status).ToString()), 
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
}
```

Am I missing any reason for which I should stick to the first approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing any reason for which I should stick to the first approach?

Two reasons, off the top of my head:

1. `ContinueWith` will use the current scheduler by default, which may cause concurrency issues or surprising behavior.
2. The antecedent task (`t` in your example) will have any exceptions wrapped in an `AggregateException` when you read the `Task.Exception` property.

I recommend using `await` instead of `ContinueWith` because it has more reasonable behavior in both of these cases. `await` will capture the current context and use that to schedule the continuation, and `await` will not wrap exceptions in `AggregateException`.

If you do use `ContinueWith`, then you should always explicitly specify a `TaskScheduler` for the continuation to run on.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I expect `ContinueWith` in the above code to always run on the same thread and context as its antecedent task - synchronously, because of `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`. That's always been the case with my tests. Is it a wrong assumption?

Comment: `ExecuteSynchronously` is a hint. There are [some conditions where it isn't honored](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/07/10265067.aspx).

Comment: Great info. Those cases would have been very hard to debug.